# Attempting to use CreateRecord Data Macro but received "No Current Record" error in MS-Access Form

Tags: ms-access, macros

I've just started learning MS-access and encountered the following problem. The database contains 2 tables namely Package and Delivery.

[Table design for Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHqp0.png)

[Table design for Delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUhL9.png)

[Relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNrU0.png)

A Form is created to facilitate data input.

Step (1) Input Package ID, Package Detail.
Step (2) Input Delivery Address.
Step (3) Save record in the Form. Then, Part 1 of the AfterInsert Data Macro (under Package Table) is triggered to update Linkage ID from 0 to [Package ID] + 1;
Step (4) Part 2 of the AfterInsert Data Macro (under Package Table) continues to create a second record by copying most content from the first one.

After several rounds of data input, the two tables are updated as follows:

[Entries in Package Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G5ER.png)
[Entries in Delivery Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFBg8.png)

Although the above tables can be updated as required, a number of "No Current Record" errors have been prompted once a new record in the Form is saved. This may be due to the fact that content under Delivery table has not yet been ready upon the AfterInsert Data Macro is triggered under the Package Table.

[Error in Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evf1q.png)

I attempted to search through the Internet but couldn't find a solution. Really appreciate if you can render me some assistance. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't use table macros. Create and save a select query that returns the data and bind the form to this query. Look up a guide on "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or similar.

Comment: I have never used data macros nor macros at all (except for AutoExec), just VBA. What exactly is LinkageID for - why is this calculated from PackageID? Consider form/subform arrangement. Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: @Gustav Thankyou for your advice. I intended to use the macros the create/update/delete relevant records as soon as a record in create in package table due to the need in the workflow. May I know if binding a form to a query can achieve the same result? I attempted to search "Beginning with Microsoft Access" but haven't figured out the exact keyword for searching. Grateful if you would give me further advice. Thank you very much!

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your reply. The LinkageID is used to grouping the two relevant items in Package Table. If any of the members in a group is deleted/updated, this LinkageID can be used to quickly identified corresponding record. I'm wondering if there's better way to achieve similar purpose as the current design is simply based on a assumption that the next Package ID is the current one plus one without taking into consideration of the need of table locking to prevent concurrent update issue. Also, thank you very much for reminding me about the naming convention.

Comment: LinkageID makes no sense to me. Your example associates two records by linkage, what if there are more than two? Doesn't the PackageID group records? Perhaps you should post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I searched for _Beginning with Microsoft Access_ and get two full pages of links to videos and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The delivery table has a one to many relationship with the package table.

You have to enter a delivery record in the delivery table before entering record in the package table.

The error is because there is no delivery id value in the delivery table, and the system expects one to exist before entering delivery id in the package table via the package form

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm just wondering why the Package Table and the Delivery Table can still be inserted properly with the desired records (using the Data Macro) even the system prompted the "No Current Record" error. I'm trying to figure out a better solution to automatically achieve the following workflow: (1) create a new record in Package Table which will create the corresponding record in Delivery table, (2) automatically create an additional record in Package Table (as a bonus item) linking with the same delivery record.

Comment: Delivery table is the parent table, record should be created there first.